# ¿Cómo puedo asegurar la APIKEY de una aplicación en Android?

Tags: android, api, seguridad

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que se hacen peticiones a una API remota, y quiero asegurar las peticiones enviando desde la app una APIKEY que sería verificada en el servidor.

El [método que explican aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553410/5587982) me pareció interesante e intenté implementarlo.

En `gradle.properties` puse esto:

```
APIKey = "24a5e678-24ce-4a3e-muchos-caracteres-mas"
```

Y luego en el `build.gradle` del módulo `app` puse esto:

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'mAPIKEY', APIKey
}
```

Para luego poder referirme a él de este modo en cualquier parte del código:

```
BuildConfig.mAPIKEY
```

Pero cuando intento sincronizar me da error:

> Could not get unknown property 'buildTypes' for project ':app' of type
>   org.gradle.api.Project.

La pregunta es ¿por qué este error?  O, si conocen alguna forma mejor de asegurar la APIKEY que me puedan sugerir.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que, tal y como dice el post, lo que aseguras es la apikey pero solo por si subes el código al repositorio de código fuente, no cuando distribuyes la aplicación ya que se puede ver si se descompila

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar la definición del buildTypes por: debug { buildConfigField 'String', 'mAPIKEY', APIKey } ?

Comment: @JaviMollá ha funcionado como dices y me recoge la APIKey perfectamente. Si quieres puedes ponerlo como respuesta. Aunque me queda la duda de cómo protegerlo mejor, ocultándolo de posibles descompilaciones. Aunque la App es distribuida solamente en Google Play Store. No creo que la puedan tomar y descompilar de ahí tan fácilmente.

Comment: Lo de descompilar la aplicación es muy fácil aunque todos exponemos claves de un modo u otro. En otra respuesta del mismo post proponen usar Firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507317/323149. Quizás es una buena idea ya que el acceso a Firebase puedes asociarlo al certificado con el que firmas la aplicación

Comment: @JaviMollá lo de `Firebase` suena interesante. Sólo que para poder usarlo en todas las solicitudes remotas de la app no me va a convenir. El `Firebase` gratuito (el cual uso en una parte de la app con poco tráfico) es limitado sobre todo en cuanto al número de conexiones concurrentes por lo que me podría traer problemas si lo uso para cada parte de la app que pida datos del servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar la definición del buildTypes para asociar la clave a la configuración de debug:

```
debug {
    buildConfigField 'String', 'mAPIKEY', APIKey
}
```

Con la de release puedes hacer lo mismo pero usando la clave con la que vayas a publicar la app. En el `gradle.properties`

```
APIKeyRelease = "cualquier-cosa"
```

En el `build.gradle`:

```
release {
    buildConfigField 'String', 'mAPIKEY', APIKeyRelease
}
```

Comment: Me queda una duda en lo que dices del `release`: ¿puede usar lo mismo verdad, o sea la misma APIKey definida en `radle.properties` como `APIKey`?

Comment: Sí, claro. Lo de poner APIKeyRelease es por si tienes dos: una para debug y otra para release

Comment: Entendido y muchísimas gracias.

Comment: De nada. Un placer